# DateTime to string format in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am having some trouble converting a DateTime variable to string.
I want to display the time using a 12-hour clock including the `AM/PM`

With the following code:

```
string timeStr = PaymentDate.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

I will get `"11:39"` but the `PM/AM` is not showing. Any guess?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül, you have to guess :p

Comment: This will help you a great deal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DateTime.ToString(string)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default.

I think your [`DateTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`AMDesignator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is empty string. That's why you can't print it with your `CurrentCulture`.

As an alternative, you can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which has `"AM"` as a `AMDesignator`) as a second parameter in  [`DateTime.ToString` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string timeStr = PaymentDate.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Inspector Gadget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Gadget) mode on: Your profile page says you are from `Ireland` and I assume your `CurrentCulture` is `en-IE`. And it's `AMDesignator` property value is empty string.

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IE").DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator;
// Prints empty string
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to force the AM/PM designator even if your current culture doesn't use it:

```
PaymentDate.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can check what your current culture's designator is by (mine is also `""` in "de-DE"):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.AMDesignator  // and .PMDesignator
```